# What is correct PHP syntax for $foo->bar :: garply()?

Tags: php

In PHP 5.3 you can do:

```
$baz::waldo();
```

Can you do the equivalent of

```
 $foo->bar::garply();   //generates an error
 {$foo->bar}::garply();    //this too
```

without resorting to

```
$baz = $foo->bar;
$baz::garply();   // while this works
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I think OP tried and got an error. So now he's wondering how to replace two lines (middle assignment) with one (direct deref).

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Possibly, but that's not clear in the question.

Comment: In short, no - you need to use a temporary variable. You'll get a syntax error on the `::` operator.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question 'what is the correct syntax?' plus 'can you do X ... without resorting to Y' indicated you couldn't do X. Reworded to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to know is to test it : **[Test demo](http://3v4l.org/on0p3)**

Giving these classes :

```
class Foo
{
    public static function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello !";
    }
}
class Bar
{
    public $apple = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apple = new Foo();
    }
}
```

This will only work from PHP 7.0.0 :

```
$foo = new Bar();
$foo->apple::hello();
```

You will get this kind of errors with the previous versions :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::'

But this :

```
$foo = new Bar();
$baz = $foo->apple;
$baz::hello();
```

will work from PHP 5.3.0 : **[Test demo](http://3v4l.org/mqreF)**